# Imported Openzeppelin contract is different than on GitHub

Tags: solidity, remix, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I am trying to import the ERC2981.sol from the OpenZeppelin contracts repository. In their GitHub page the `royaltyInfo` is a `public` function. But for some reason when I import it in my project, this function is `external`. This is the function (which is public):

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/5a75065659a65e65bb04890192e3a4bcb7917fff/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol#L43

But on Remix this is what it looks like and is `external` (inside `.debs/npm/@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/token/commonERC2981.sol`)

[image]

And this is how I import it:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/token/common/ERC2981.sol";
```

And I am using `0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7` as a solidity compiler in Remix.

**My question is:** How can I resolve this issue? I can change the `external` to `public` in my hardhat deployment but I don't like to do this (changing manually).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this change has occurred within the last 3 weeks, and v4.5.0 was released on February 9th. Try using pre-release @4.6.0-rc.0 instead of @4.5.0 in the import statement. Be carful when using these pre releases as there can be bugs. You should be fine, but I would review the code that you are looking at in that GitHub before deploying to Mainnet.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0-rc.0/token/common/ERC2981.sol";
```

Comment: Yeah but this is also not inside the @4.6.0-rc.0 release. I guess they are waiting for "something"?!. I'll wait for an actual release.

Comment: Try this `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol"`

Comment: I believe that this will pull straight from the Github page with the current changes that have taken effect.

Comment: It gets the latest release and this is not in the latest release. Maybe I can override this function but how?

Comment: try `import "@openzepplin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol"` This points to the main branch rather than a release branch. The main branch is where the new commits were added to. I did not test this for myself, but I did see if my IDE registered it as valid and it did.

Comment: But on remix it said: not found @openzepplin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol

Comment: interesting, this worked for me. I'll look at it a bit more tomorrow.